# ejabberd live run toolbar start, but failed

Tags: erlang, ejabberd

I open a shell, and run "ejabberdctl live";
it return "ejabberd 2.1.13 is started in the node ejabberd@localhost", when  run "toolbar:start().", it return "** exception error: undefined function toolbar:start/0"

why?

Comment: What is it `toolbar`?

Comment: I guess it's GUI tool